# Getting results from a database query in SQL and displaying them in a datagrid view

Tags: c#, sql, database

My problem is that i dont know enought about linking sql databases with c# code but what im trying to do is send a search query to my sql database and display the results back onto a data grid view. My problem lay within the returning and displaying the data. Below is my search method i created in the search button click event method:

```
// takes one of the parameters and searches the data base for all rows that match the parameter and argument
private void SearchBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(searchCB.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            selectedItem = "HaulerName";
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedItem = "TicketNumber";
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedItem = "LeaseName";
            break;
        case 3:
            selectedItem = "TicketDate";
            break;
        case 4:
            selectedItem = "CustomerName";
            break;
        case 5: 
            selectedItem = "LeaseOperator";
            break;
        case 6:
            selectedItem = "ProductName";
            break;
    }
    if (selectedItem.Equals("TicketDate") == false)
    {
        query = "SELECT * FROM DisposalData.dbo.ThirdPartyDisposal WHERE " + selectedItem + " LIKE '" + searchTB.Text.ToString() + "%';";
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    }


}
```

ive run the debugger and it works fine and executes i just cant for the life of me figure out how to put the results in the data grid view table. Any help and as much explanation as possible would be great, thanks a bunch!

Comment: You have bigger problems to address before doing anything else - SQL injection vulnerabilities. Also, you're going a very archaic and somewhat legacy route - take a look at the number of database frameworks available in .NET. Even Linq2Sql, with its being superceded by Entity Framework, would potentially be a better choice.

Comment: I didn't leave. And the phrase is so common, the words "injection" and "vulnerabilities" ideally causing reflexive pangs to any developer or person of general logic, that it works as a sign post: a quick Google will yield copious data on the topic, and even reading the Wikipedia page alone would be decent initiative. I just provided the incentive.

Comment: (SQL) injection is the #1 item listed in web application security by OWASP.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read into [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For code to work Replace this

```
sqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

with

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 da.Fill(ds, "ss");

 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
```

if using webforms add this line, in winforms ignore it

```
 dataGridView1.DataBind();
```